Are questions about preparing for a psychology degree on topic?
How to prepare when entering the field of Psychology from a professional UX background? is asking about how to best prepare for a UK conversion course in Psychology and has been closed. It has 3 related questions

Would you have any specific advice for someone in my position?
Are there any definitive resources I should be aware of? And why those ones?
If you came to Psychology from a similar background, which particular skills and concepts did you find useful or wish you knew before entering an MSc conversion course?

I think this could have a very nice answer from someone who has done a lot of teaching/admin on an conversion course. I don't have this expertise, but the little experience I had with my former departments conversion course was that all the faculty teaching on it were surprised about the variety of deficiencies the students had.
Conversion courses are highly compressed and therefore make assumptions, in my experience often unfounded, about what incoming students know. It would not surprise me if some conversion courses provide an introductory reading list or handbook for incoming students, or at a minimum have explored and dismissed the ideas. This would cover the first two parts of the question in a pretty objective way. There might even be guidelines now from BPS.
The third could have objective evidence from where past students struggled.

I think we need a general "are education / career path questions on-topic here" question on Meta.  The closest I found is this one.  As this is a forum focused on research in cognitive science, my feeling is no.  Additionally, the above linked question, and the 3 related questions, all seem to me to be primarily opinion-based, so even if we permitted such questions, I worry that many would be off-topic anyhow.  My understanding is that Academia.SE does not accept such questions either for that reason.

@ArnonWeinberg asking about a specific program seems too localized and likely to be opinion based. How to prepare for a typical aspect of becoming a psychologist seems very much on topic here. I am a mod at AC.SE and we would migrate a question like this to the field specific site. A question asking about a specific program we would close outright.

Interesting, good to know.  Do you find that other stacks accept such questions?  eg, History.SE about a history degree or career path, or English.SE about that field?

@ArnonWeinberg we tend to not get to many of them and I don't really follow them, but searching for career closed:0 is:question seems to suggest that these types of question are not highly voted, but at least some survive many of the specialty sites. There doesn't appear to be anything on history.se, but I am not sure they are the same as AI, Astronomy, Biology, AI, ...

@StrongBad on Bio these kinds of Qs are readily closed. Mostly with a comment it's better suited for Academia.SE but that's not the case imo. Whatever the site, I think these Qs are often too broad, too opinion based, and open for discussion and hence offtopic on a scientific stack.

"were surprised about the variety of deficiencies the students had" That would be part of the problem no, making it opinion based? You are just pushing the line of what is objective/subjective. I believe the question can be written in a more objective way, but currently it is not.
